# How to find an element with a specific "left" value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So lets say i have the following html:

```
<div class="con">
    <ul>
        <li class="a">1</li>
        <li class="b">2</li>
        <li class="c">3</li>
        <li class="d">4</li>
        <li class="e">5</li>
        <li class="f">6</li>
        <li class="g">7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Lets say i have given `<li class="g">` an absolute position of `-20px` (and the containing div `.con` has a relative position).

How would i tell jquery to select the LI element at `-20px` within the `.con` div and do an action on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the `li` elements and filter out the one using a function:

```
$('.con li').filter(function(){ return $(this).position().left == 20; })
```